# Google Classroom: Find userId from the google doc

Tags: google-classroom

How can I find the userId of the student to which a `CourseWorkSubmission` has been submitted?

Steps:

- Student is assigned coursework using Google Classrooms.
- Teacher views coursework (docs.google.com URL).
- I click Add On, to try and pull out student info, but can't find the context for the student (e.g. userId, actorId) or even the submissionId in order to make a call to the API to get the information.

Any help or pointers gratefully received :)

References:
Have checked out the Google Classroom API:
https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/get

And the Google Drive API:
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk

Answer (score 0):

When you do your get of the studentSubmission here https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/get the response will contain a userId. That userID is the Students google ID you're looking for.

Go ahead and run the Try this API functionality on the https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/get page and you should see what I"m talking about.

The full response information is listed here https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions

If you're having a problem finding the relevant courseWork ID, then use the list capability here https://developers.google.com/classroom/reference/rest/v1/courses.courseWork.studentSubmissions/list (Put a - in for the courseWorkId)